# wordpress wp_handle_upload not moving the file

Tags: wordpress, upload

Can someone tell me why this function is not moving the uploaded files anywhere.

```
function handle_logo_upload($option){
    if(!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
{

            require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                                    }


            if(!empty($_FILES["site_logo_custom"])){

$theFile=$_FILES["site_logo_custom"];

$overrides=array('test_form'=>false);

$urls=wp_handle_upload($theFile,$overrides);
$temp=$urls["url"];
return $temp;

                                    }


                                    return $option;
                                }
```

I can't really find too much about wp_handle_upload function.
Thankss!!!

Comment: And where this function is staying?And its not being getting called by someone i see? How you are running this function as a form action?

Comment: hi Sajjadur, It is in my theme's function template. It's a field of the setting page I found this approach in some tutorials after googling for a while. I found an other approach based on jQuery , but I prefer to leave the collection of the data on php.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your form is formatted kinda like this :

```
form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> //action is current post
 <input type="file" name="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And to upload the file to the wordpress upload folder using wp_handle_upload(); function you may use below code....

```
function handle_logo_upload($file){

require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
$uploadedfile = $file;

$movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, array('test_form' => false)); 

if ( $movefile ){
    echo $movefile['url'];
    //or return
    return $movefile['url'];
  }

}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   handle_logo_upload($_FILES['file']);
}
```

Comment: If you want to do additional security checking then you can do it right inside your function.i didn't add security checks for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Hi Sajjadur, my code is slidely the same. I'm using it in a form created in settings API. My intention is to set  a logo  upload button for in the theme settings page.

Comment: then use wordpress media uploader and get the image the url and save it into {prefix}_settings database....

Comment: I had a look, that's just a jquery plugin, making things more visible and smooth, it still won't fix the mess with my upload.

Comment: Maybe its a specific site based problem then cause the code is working on my site..Then just on the wp_debug and get the error result.

Comment: i;ve tried wp_debug, no error echoed. I think the problem is that my sanitize callback function is not triggered at all for some reason. Because of that, all the form is doing is to pass the filename to the option table.I found some simillar issues here, but they are not solved.

Comment: Well You can contact me personally if you want and show me your site code so that i can debug what the heck going on???

Comment: My "reputation" is not enough for chat :).

Comment: Contact Me skype then : sagordev672@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your function is called perfectly.

```
function handle_logo_upload($option){
    if(!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
    {

        require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    }
    //you are using empty version make sure your php version is higher than 5.2
    if(!empty($_FILES["site_logo_custom"])){
        $move_logo = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES["site_logo_custom"], array('test_form' => false) );
        if ( $move_logo && !isset($move_logo['error']) ) {
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $attachment = array(
                'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($move_logo['file']),
                'post_mime_type' => $move_logo['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($move_logo['file']) ),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $logo_attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $move_logo['file']);
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $logo_attach_id );
            if ( $image_attributes ) {
              return $image_attributes[0]; 
             }
             else
             {
                return $option;
             }
        }else{
            return $option;
        }
    }else{
        return $option;
    }

}
```

Please read my comments written in code

Comment: Back again, using the function given by you Arkshay some changes got occured, but is still not usefull . My php version is 7.1.1 . At the moment the function returns this string : 88974.ngsversion.1463419670135.adapt.676.1.jpg . It's seems to be save as an option. I can call it using, get_option('site_logo_custom'). But I can't find it in the options database table.  The file is still not moved anywhere.

Comment: $image_attributes, do the print r are you getting full image path in that array ? Please check